# Venkman's javascript debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm trying to understand if I can debug a stand alone .js file which doesn't interact with browser. Is there any way to just load it and debug or I will be forced to encapsulate it into html file?

Environment is Windows, no browser objects are required.

Comment: First thing you should do is describe what environment you're going to be using this file in, since that will affect your choice of debugger. So we know it's not going to be executing in a browser, where will you be running it? Windows Shell? Rhino? Node.js? WebKit?

Comment: As you have no browser interaction why not use cscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug a stand-alone script, my first thought would be to use [Rhino debugger](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/debugger.html) -- have you tried that?  I've also heard about [v8 debug](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol), but I have no experience with it yet.

Comment: I'll check that but first glance is not so impressive... any other options?